# Unicode decode error when installing polyglot

Tags: python, pip, python-unicode, polyglot

I encountered a problem installing `polyglot` with `pip install polyglot`.
I checked the `setup.py`, the encoding is `utf-8`, which is supposedly correct for all languages.
I tried changing the encoding to `utf-16` but the same problem occured.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'e:\anaconda\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
'"'"'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\pip-install-4718m132\\polyglot\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\WINDOWS\\TEMP\\pip-install-4718m132\\polyglot\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pip-pip-egg-info-0ny0ymtc'
         cwd: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pip-install-4718m132\polyglot\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pip-install-4718m132\polyglot\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        readme = readme_file.read()
      File "e:\anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 4941: character maps to <undefined>
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I don't know whether I should make any changes to the `cp1252.py` or the `setup.py` for polyglot.

Python version: 3.6.10

Comment: Please check [this](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/127) post -

Comment: solved, thanks a lot. Now I understand how to solve these kinds of problem thanks to you

Comment: That's ok. I've posted it as an answer now, and it will be great if you accept it. Just as a suggestion, try Googling your problem before asking a question, as there is a high chance of getting better answers faster.

Comment: I googled it, I just didn't check the issues page in the GitHub. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: Oh that's nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows needs a special installation process. Check [this](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/127) post for more information